# Overload a method using traits

Tags: rust, traits

I'm struggling to simulate method overloading using traits in Rust where there are multiple types involved.

In C++ I would write

```cpp
struct PdlDict {
     void update(const string&,const string&, double x) {...}
     void update(const string&,const string&, const string x) {...}
};
```

and call it

```cpp
 PdlDict d;
 d.update(123.0);
 d.update("foo");
```

In Rust for this `PdlDict` struct

```
pub struct PdlDict {
    pub pdl_items: Vec<PdlItem>,
}
impl PdlDict {
    fn new() -> PdlDict {
        PdlDict {
            pdl_items: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
}
```

I implemented this trait which works

```
trait UpdatePdl {
    fn update(&self, item: &PdlDict, object_name: &str, name: &str);
}
impl<'a> UpdatePdl for &'a str {
    fn update(&self, item: &PdlDict, object_name: &str, name: &str) {}
}
impl<'a> UpdatePdl for f32 {
    fn update(&self, item: &PdlDict, object_name: &str, name: &str) {}
}
```

Calling doesn't feel ergonomic as I have to pass the object that want to update as the first argument:

```
"bar".update(&pdl, "r", "result");
64.0.update(&pdl, "r", "result");
```

What is the a more appropriate way to achieve the same semantics in a idiomatic Rust way?

I suspect it's a combination of traits and templates but I can't think how to approach this.

**Edit**
Note this question is not asking how to implement inheritance using traits. I've already done this in this example and it works fine. It's asking for an way of expressing inheritance in a style as given above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, the idiomatic way would be writing something like what you did, and then add the ergonomics with:

```
impl PdlDict {
    fn update<T: UpdatePdl>(&self, object_name: &str, name: &str, t: T) {
        t.update(&self, object_name, name)
    }
}
```